# Best way to create unique username

Tags: sql, node.js

When a user crate his account i want to generate a **simple** unique username. Something like this :

username = (FIRSTNAME.charAt(0) + LASTNAME).toLowerCase();

In my project i have more than 100k user.
So several have the same username.
If the username already exist i want to add +1 to the username.

Example :

- jdoe
- jdoe1
- jdoe +n

Now i want to know which number i have to add to my username.

I have 2 solutions :

1. A recursive function who select the `username + i`. I will have 1 - 10 select on my BDD before find which number i have to use.
2. Use thekeyword `LIKE%`. I guess it's worst because i will search on 100k + username rather than ~10

There is other way to do that ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Allow them to create a username and you won't have to do it programatically. Since users would not be allowed to create an existing username you won't be having a problem but if you were to use their first and lastnames to create a unique username what do you do when their names are the same?. If we both can just create a username and both of us are John Doe (same first and last name) then only one of us should be able to create a username of jdoe57

So logic would be in the initial assessment that checks to see if a username is already taken and alert the user; same with email address